# recuperar um nome de cliente em um array multidimensional

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Estou criando um script para executar procedures no banco de dados de alguns clientes, Tenho os seguintes arrays com as credenciais de cada um:

```
$hosts["Cliente1"] =  array("ip"=> "ip_do_cliente", "usuario" => "usuario","senha" => "12345","base" => "conadmin","porta" => "3306");
$hosts["Cliente2"] =  array("ip"=> "ip_do_cliente", "usuario" => "usuario","senha" => "12345","base" => "conadmin","porta" => "3306");
$hosts["Cliente3"] = array("ip"=> "ip_do_cliente", "usuario" => "usuario","senha" => "12345","base" => "conadmin","porta" => "3306");
```

eu faço um foreach para conectar em cada um deles, desta forma:

```
foreach ($hosts as $key=>$host) 
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($host['ip'], $host['usuario'], $host['senha'], $host['base'], $host['porta']);
    }
```

Em caso de sucesso, eu faço uma query para salvar no meu banco de dados,desta forma:

```
            $data = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
            $ip_cliente = $host['ip'];
            $cliente = ????; 
            $mensagem = 'Teste Executado com sucesso!';

            $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO pbx_teste_permissao(ip_cliente, data_teste, mensagem)"
                    . "values('%s','%s','%s', '%s')",$ip_cliente, $data, $cliente, $mensagem);

            pg_query($query);
```

eu queria armazenar também o nome do cliente, como eu poderia retornar do foreach o nome do cliente e preencher a variável **$cliente** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o nome do cliente é o item usuário no seu array use-o, se não iria o nome:

```
s["Cliente1"] =  array("ip"=> "ip_do_cliente", "usuario" => "usuario", "nome_do_cliente" => "nome_do_cliente", senha" => "12345","base" => "conadmin","porta" => "3306");
```

depois dentro do foreach defina a variável cliente:

```
foreach ($hosts as $key=>$host) 
    {    
        $nome_do_cliente= $host['nome_do_cliente'];
        $conn = mysqli_connect($host['ip'], $host['usuario'], $host['senha'], $host['base'], $host['porta']);
    }
```

Quando ele for fazer o insert:

```
$data = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
            $ip_cliente = $host['ip'];
            $cliente = $nome_do_cliente; 
            $mensagem = 'Teste Executado com sucesso!';

            $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO pbx_teste_permissao(ip_cliente, data_teste, mensagem)"
                    . "values('%s','%s','%s', '%s')",$ip_cliente, $data, $cliente, $mensagem);

            pg_query($query);
```

Comment: só tem uma coisa que preciso alinhar contigo, esse insert vem dentro do foreach ou fora?

Comment: ele vai dentro do foreach, perdão quando fui colocar o código aqui eu não me atentei ao detalhe da chave.

Comment: de boas minha reposta funciona pra vc entao, se ele nao tivesse ia ser necessario um array,

Comment: entendi ! Muito obrigado Julio !